# Issue on running the HelloWorld alexa-skill-kit Sample from the Command Line

Tags: java, maven, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to run [Hello world](https://github.com/alexa/skill-samples-java/tree/master/helloworld) alexa skill kit java sample from command line using this [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/deploy-a-sample-skill-as-a-web-service.html#h3_run_cmdline). I am able to build the jar successfully but I am getting the below exception on trying to run the sample with `mvn exec:java -Dexec.executable=”java” -DdisableRequestSignatureCheck=true` command

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Launcher
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run 

`mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package`

 in the command line?
Just follow the README in this [page](https://github.com/alexa/skill-samples-java/tree/master/helloworld).